# Are there any good solutions for putting a radial basis kernel support vector machine into production?

Tags: svm

Are there any good options for a radial basis kernel `SVM` where I can serialize the model to store and later deserialize and evaluate? I'm using `H2O` for some other things and it supports SVM but no radial basis kernel.

Comment: If you are using Python, you can use `pickle` for that. Not 100% if it works with H2O though. In R, you can use `saveRDS`.

Comment: How does this answer the request for a radial basis kernel SVM?

Comment: Whether it is radial basis or not, the model in whichever language was created and fitted, will be some object that can be serialized with e.g. pickle or saveRDS.

Comment: This answers my question, I didn't realize R had a mechanism to serialize arbitrary objects, that is very helpful.